# Changing the top margin of the proof environment

Tags: environments, amsmath, thmtools

In my opinion the `proof` environment has too big of a top margin. I'd like to have it visually closer to the proposition or theorem it refers to.

I have verified that adding `\vspace{-3ex}` before a `proof` environment gets me the result I want. Now, how do I modify the proof environment?

I tried to redefine it, but I don't know the original definition and I didn't find it in my Latex distribution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=\topsep,
    spacebelow=\topsep,
    name={\color{Blue}Proposition},
]{propsty}
\declaretheorem[style=propsty]{prop}

\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
    This is a proposition.
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}
    The proof is left as an exercise for the reader.
\end{proof}

\begin{prop}
    This is another proposition.
\end{prop}

\vspace{-3ex}
\begin{proof}
    The proof is left as an exercise for the reader and it's closer to the
    relevant proposition.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Choosing a negative value for `spacebelow` didn't seem to do anything. So I decided to change the proof environment.

Comment: we don't know where the definition of proof is either.  please provode a small compilable example that shows the problem.  and remember, a proof does not always follow directly after the theorem or proposition it refers to; in such a case, the extra space would be useful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm sorry, I added a MWE to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this, for instance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=0\topsep,
    spacebelow=0\topsep,
    name={\color{Blue}Proposition},
]{propsty}
\declaretheorem[style=propsty]{prop}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=0.5\topsep,
    spacebelow=0.5\topsep,
    name={\color{Blue}Proposition},
]{propsty}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=0.5\topsep,
    spacebelow=1\topsep,
    name=Proof,
    headfont=\itshape, numbered=no
]{proofsty}
\declaretheorem[style=proofsty]{myproof}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
    This is a proposition.
\end{prop}

\begin{myproof}
    The proof is left as an exercise for the reader.
\end{myproof}

\begin{prop}
    This is another proposition.
\end{prop}


\begin{myproof}
    The proof is left as an exercise for the reader and it's closer to the
    relevant proposition.
\end{myproof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Is there a way to redefine the `proof` environment so that I can keep that same name?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know `amsthm` very well (personally, I use ntheorem). The `ntheorem` package allows declarations like `\renewtheorem` or `\renewtheoremstyle`.